# Check if list of objects have two items the same javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of objects that look like this :

```
Object {title: "The Amaze - 2016-12-31 10:00", date: "10/12/2016", time: "10.00am"…}
Object {title: "The Amaze - 2016-12-31 12:00", date: "31/12/2016", time: "12.00am"…}
Object {title: "The Amaze - 2016-12-31 10:00", date: "31/12/2016", time: "10.00am"…}
```

I'm trying to loop through this list of `object` and have a conditional statement that says if the dates match then do something.

The `dateArray` is my list of objects. Probably bad practice calling it an array in its name but..

```
        for (var j = 0; j < dateArray.length; j++) {
            if (dateArray[j].date === sDate) {

                if (dateArray[j].date === dateArray[j].date) {
                    console.log(dateArray[j], "<<<<< Matched");
                }

            }
        }
```

Could anyone explain how i'd achieve what i'm trying to do.

Also, `sDate` is just a variable i've delcared at the top which gets the current date.

Comment: what are you doing in second if statement?? do you want to compare 2 objects ??

Comment: Yeah, the second if statement is my problem. It comes back as matched for everything. I'm trying to say if one object.date matches another then do something @Vicmathur

Comment: `sDate` is just a variable that grabs the current date @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: if (dateArray[j].date === dateArray[j].date) will give always true you can try if (dateArray[j].date === dateArray[j+1].date)

Comment: which 2 object you want to compare ?? any 2 which have same date ??

Comment: @Vicmathur yes, basically if any of the objects in that list have the same date, then do something. Thanks, i'll try your above suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object and a single loop. The object works as hash table for the date and if exist, then a match is found.

```js
var array = [{ title: "The Amaze - 2016-12-31 10:00", date: "10/12/2016", time: "10.00am" }, { title: "The Amaze - 2016-12-31 12:00", date: "31/12/2016", time: "12.00am" }, { title: "The Amaze - 2016-12-31 10:00", date: "31/12/2016", time: "10.00am" }];

array.forEach(function (a, i) {
    if (this[a.date]) {
        console.log('match @ ' + i);
    }
    this[a.date] = true;
}, Object.create(null));
```

Proposal with keeping the indices of a date

```js
var array = [{ title: "The Amaze - 2016-12-31 10:00", date: "10/12/2016", time: "10.00am" }, { title: "The Amaze - 2016-12-31 12:00", date: "31/12/2016", time: "12.00am" }, { title: "The Amaze - 2016-12-31 10:00", date: "31/12/2016", time: "10.00am" }];

array.forEach(function (a, i) {
    if (this[a.date]) {
        console.log('match @ ' + i + ' with ' + this[a.date]);
    }
    this[a.date] = this[a.date] || [];
    this[a.date].push(i);
}, Object.create(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  this will check every combination you can change loop condition

```
        for (var j = 0; j < dateArray.length; j++)
        {
            for (var k =0 ; k < dateArray.length; k++)
            {
                if(k==j)
                {
                     continue;  // this is same object
                }  
                else
                {  
                    if (dateArray[j].date === dateArray[k].date) {
                    console.log(dateArray[j], "<<<<< Matched");
                }
            }

        }
```